# Sort countries per continent

Tags: iphone, ios, flurry, nslocale

is there a way to get the continent of an specific country?

I'm using Flurry's API and it returns a JSON separated by countries, I need the data in Contintents so I want an array for every contintent with his countries inside, for example:

```
NSArray * europe = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"ES", @"IT", @"FR", ... , nil];
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For heaven's sake, use subscripting: `NSArray *europe = @[@"ES", @"IT", @"EN", ...]`

Comment: If `JSON` contains variable with continent or only countries?

Comment: Are you looking for a webservice that can get you the list of all the countries in a continent?

Comment: Make a database your self...not that many countries i guess

Comment: @Cyrille how is it better to have @[@"ES"...] instead of [NSArray alloc] initWithObjects?

Comment: I think that's only a more confortable and fastest way to do it

Comment: Dunno, don't you find it more readable? That's the way that Apple advocates in their effort to modernizing the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
private static HashMap<String,String> countryMap=new HashMap<String,String>(); 
private final static String EUROPE="E";
private final static String NORTH_AMERICA="N";
private final static String SOUTH_AMERICA="S";
private final static String AFRICA="AF";
private final static String ASIA="AS";
private final static String OCEANIA="O";
private final static String ANTARTIDA="ANT";

 static
    {
     countryMap.put("AF", "AS");
     countryMap.put("AL", "E");
     countryMap.put("DE", "E");
     countryMap.put("DZ", "E");
     countryMap.put("AD", "E");
     countryMap.put("AQ", "ANT");
     countryMap.put("AG", "S");
     countryMap.put("SA", "AS");
     countryMap.put("AR", "S");
     countryMap.put("AM", "AS");
     countryMap.put("AW", "S");
     countryMap.put("AU", "O");
     countryMap.put("AZ", "AS");
     countryMap.put("AT", "E");
     countryMap.put("BS", "S");
     countryMap.put("BH", "AS");
     countryMap.put("BD", "AS");
     countryMap.put("BB", "S");
     countryMap.put("BZ", "S");
     countryMap.put("BJ", "AF");
     countryMap.put("BM", "S");
     countryMap.put("BE", "E");
     countryMap.put("BT", "AS");
     countryMap.put("BE", "E");
     countryMap.put("BO", "S");
     countryMap.put("BW", "AF");
     countryMap.put("BA", "E");
     countryMap.put("BR", "S");
     countryMap.put("BN", "AS");
     countryMap.put("BG", "E");
     countryMap.put("BF", "AF");
     countryMap.put("BI", "AF");
     countryMap.put("KH", "AS");
     countryMap.put("CM", "AF");
     countryMap.put("CA", "N");
     countryMap.put("CV", "AF");
     countryMap.put("BQ", "S");
     countryMap.put("AF", "AS");
     countryMap.put("CO", "S");
     countryMap.put("KM", "AF");
     countryMap.put("CG", "AF");
     countryMap.put("CD", "AF");
     countryMap.put("KP", "AS");
     countryMap.put("KR", "AS");
     countryMap.put("CR", "S");
     countryMap.put("CI", "AF");
     countryMap.put("HR", "E");
     countryMap.put("CU", "S");
     countryMap.put("CW", "S");
     countryMap.put("DK", "E");
     countryMap.put("DJ", "AF");
     countryMap.put("DM", "S");
     countryMap.put("EG", "AF");
     countryMap.put("SV", "S");
     countryMap.put("EC", "S");
     countryMap.put("ER", "AF");
     countryMap.put("SK", "E");
     countryMap.put("SI", "E");
     countryMap.put("ES", "E");
     countryMap.put("US", "N");
     countryMap.put("EE", "E");
     countryMap.put("ET", "AF");
     countryMap.put("FJ", "O");
     countryMap.put("PH", "AS");
     countryMap.put("FI", "E");
     countryMap.put("FR", "E");
     countryMap.put("GA", "AF");
     countryMap.put("GM", "AF");
     countryMap.put("GE", "E");
     countryMap.put("GH", "AF");
     countryMap.put("GI", "E");
     countryMap.put("GD", "S");
     countryMap.put("GL", "N");
     countryMap.put("GP", "S");
     countryMap.put("GF", "S");
     countryMap.put("GU", "AF");
     countryMap.put("GT", "S");
     countryMap.put("GG", "E");
     countryMap.put("GN", "AF");
     countryMap.put("GW", "AF");
     countryMap.put("GQ", "AF");
     countryMap.put("GY", "S");
     countryMap.put("HT", "S");
     countryMap.put("HN", "S");
     countryMap.put("HN", "E");
     countryMap.put("IE", "AS");
     countryMap.put("BV", "ANT");
     countryMap.put("CX", "O");
     countryMap.put("HM", "ANT");
     countryMap.put("AF", "O");
     countryMap.put("IM", "E");
     countryMap.put("RE", "AF");
     countryMap.put("KY", "S");
     countryMap.put("CC", "O");
     countryMap.put("CK", "O");
     countryMap.put("FO", "E");
     countryMap.put("GS", "ANT");
     countryMap.put("FK", "S");
     countryMap.put("MP", "O");
     countryMap.put("MH", "O");
     countryMap.put("UM", "O");
     countryMap.put("PN", "S");
     countryMap.put("SB", "O");
     countryMap.put("TC", "S");
     countryMap.put("VG", "S");
     countryMap.put("VI", "S");
     countryMap.put("ID", "AS");
     countryMap.put("IR", "AS");
     countryMap.put("IQ", "AS");
     countryMap.put("IE", "E");
     countryMap.put("IS", "E");
     countryMap.put("IL", "AS");
     countryMap.put("IT", "E");
     countryMap.put("IN", "AS");
     countryMap.put("JM", "S");
     countryMap.put("JP", "AS");
     countryMap.put("JE", "E");
     countryMap.put("JO", "AS");
     countryMap.put("KZ", "AS");
     countryMap.put("KE", "AF");
     countryMap.put("KG", "AS");
     countryMap.put("KI", "O");
     countryMap.put("KW", "AS");
     countryMap.put("LA", "AS");
     countryMap.put("LV", "E");
     countryMap.put("LR", "AF");
     countryMap.put("LI", "E");
     countryMap.put("LT", "E");
     countryMap.put("LB", "AS");
     countryMap.put("LY", "AF");
     countryMap.put("LU", "E");
     countryMap.put("MK", "E");
     countryMap.put("MG", "AF");
     countryMap.put("MW", "AF");
     countryMap.put("MV", "AS");
     countryMap.put("ML", "AF");
     countryMap.put("MT", "E");
     countryMap.put("MA", "AF");
     countryMap.put("MQ", "S");
     countryMap.put("MU", "AF");
     countryMap.put("MR", "AF");
     countryMap.put("YT", "AF");
     countryMap.put("MX", "N");
     countryMap.put("FM", "O");
     countryMap.put("MZ", "AF");
     countryMap.put("MD", "E");
     countryMap.put("MN", "AS");
     countryMap.put("ME", "E");
     countryMap.put("MS", "S");
     countryMap.put("MC", "E");
     countryMap.put("MM", "AS");
     countryMap.put("NA", "AF");
     countryMap.put("NR", "O");
     countryMap.put("NP", "AS");
     countryMap.put("NI", "S");
     countryMap.put("NG", "AF");
     countryMap.put("NU", "O");
     countryMap.put("NE", "AF");
     countryMap.put("NO","E");
     countryMap.put("NC", "O");
     countryMap.put("NZ", "O");
     countryMap.put("OM", "AS");
     countryMap.put("NL", "E");
     countryMap.put("PK", "AS");
     countryMap.put("PW", "O");
     countryMap.put("PS", "AS");
     countryMap.put("PA", "S");
     countryMap.put("PG", "O");
     countryMap.put("PY", "S");
     countryMap.put("PE", "S");
     countryMap.put("PF", "O");
     countryMap.put("PL", "E");
     countryMap.put("PT", "E");
     countryMap.put("PR", "S");
     countryMap.put("QA", "AS");
     countryMap.put("HK", "AS");
     countryMap.put("MO", "AS");
     countryMap.put("GB", "E");
     countryMap.put("CF", "E");
     countryMap.put("DO", "S");
     countryMap.put("CZ", "E");
     countryMap.put("ZA", "AF");
     countryMap.put("RO", "E");
     countryMap.put("RU", "E");
     countryMap.put("RW", "AF");
     countryMap.put("UM", "S");
     countryMap.put("KN", "S");
     countryMap.put("SH", "AF");
     countryMap.put("LC", "S");
     countryMap.put("MF", "S");
     countryMap.put("VC", "S");
     countryMap.put("PM", "N");
     countryMap.put("WS", "O");
     countryMap.put("AS", "O");
     countryMap.put("SM", "E");
     countryMap.put("EH", "AF");
     countryMap.put("ST", "AF");
     countryMap.put("SN", "AF");
     countryMap.put("SC", "AF");
     countryMap.put("RS", "E");
     countryMap.put("SL", "AF");
     countryMap.put("SG", "AS");         
     countryMap.put("SR", "S");
     countryMap.put("SJ", "E");
     countryMap.put("SZ", "AF");
     countryMap.put("TJ", "AS");
     countryMap.put("TH", "AS");
     countryMap.put("TW", "AS");
     countryMap.put("TZ", "AF");
     countryMap.put("IO", "O");
     countryMap.put("TF", "O");
     countryMap.put("TL", "AS");
     countryMap.put("TG", "AF");
     countryMap.put("TK", "O");
     countryMap.put("TO", "O");
     countryMap.put("TT", "S");
     countryMap.put("TN", "AF");
     countryMap.put("TM", "AS");
     countryMap.put("TR", "AS");
     countryMap.put("TV", "O");
     countryMap.put("TD", "AF");
     countryMap.put("UA", "E");
     countryMap.put("UG", "AF");
     countryMap.put("AE", "AS");
     countryMap.put("UY", "S");
     countryMap.put("UZ", "AS");
     countryMap.put("VZ", "O");
     countryMap.put("VA", "E");
     countryMap.put("VE", "S");
     countryMap.put("VN", "AS");
     countryMap.put("WF", "O");
     countryMap.put("CL", "S");
     countryMap.put("CN", "AS");
     countryMap.put("CY", "E");
     countryMap.put("ZM", "AF");
     countryMap.put("ZW", "AF");
    }
```

Comment: That's not objective-C.

Answer (score 2):

Declare a reverse lookup dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *continentForCountries = @{
    @"FR": @"Europe",
    @"IT": @"Europe",
    @"US": @"North America",
    @"CA": @"North America",
    ...
}
```

Then you can group countries into continents using `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock`, inside which you accumulate countries into a dictionary of arrays, whose keys are the continent names :

```
NSArray *countries = @[...];
NSArray *continentForCountries = @[...];

NSMutableDictionary *countriesByContinents = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[countries enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *country, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSString *continent = continentForCountries[country];
    if (countriesByContinents[continent] == nil)
        countriesByContinents[continent] = [NSMutableArray new];
    [countriesByContinents[continent] addObject:country];
}];
```

Comment: Note that I don't handle the case where you forgot an entry in `continentForCountries`, this is left as an exercise.

Comment: That's a good way to do it but I was asking for a nsdictionary or nsarrays that were already done. As I don't find anything, I'm going to do it myself. Thanks!

PD: I feel more confortable with the old declaration ;) old ways...

Comment: Then maybe you'll find what you want here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/26214/where-can-i-get-iso-lists-for-continent-country-and-currency-to-use-on-my-web

Answer (score 1):

Here is the NSDictionary I have created:

```
    countryPerContinent = @{@"AF":@"AS",
                            @"AL":@"E",
                            @"DE":@"E",
                            @"DZ":@"E",
                            @"AD":@"E",
                            @"AQ":@"ANT",
                            @"AG":@"S",
                            @"SA":@"AS",
                            @"AR":@"S",
                            @"AM":@"AS",
                            @"AW":@"S",
                            @"AU":@"O",
                            @"AZ":@"AS",
                            @"AT":@"E",
                            @"BS":@"S",
                            @"BH":@"AS",
                            @"BD":@"AS",
                            @"BB":@"S",
                            @"BZ":@"S",
                            @"BJ":@"AF",
                            @"BM":@"S",
                            @"BE":@"E",
                            @"BT":@"AS",
                            @"BO":@"S",
                            @"BW":@"AF",
                            @"BA":@"E",
                            @"BR":@"S",
                            @"BN":@"AS",
                            @"BG":@"E",
                            @"BF":@"AF",
                            @"BI":@"AF",
                            @"KH":@"AS",
                            @"CM":@"AF",
                            @"CA":@"N",
                            @"CV":@"AF",
                            @"BQ":@"S",
                            @"AF":@"AS",
                            @"CO":@"S",
                            @"KM":@"AF",
                            @"CG":@"AF",
                            @"CD":@"AF",
                            @"KP":@"AS",
                            @"KR":@"AS",
                            @"CR":@"S",
                            @"CI":@"AF",
                            @"HR":@"E",
                            @"CU":@"S",
                            @"CW":@"S",
                            @"DK":@"E",
                            @"DJ":@"AF",
                            @"DM":@"S",
                            @"EG":@"AF",
                            @"SV":@"S",
                            @"EC":@"S",
                            @"ER":@"AF",
                            @"SK":@"E",
                            @"SI":@"E",
                            @"ES":@"AF",
                            @"US":@"N",
                            @"EE":@"E",
                            @"ET":@"AF",
                            @"FJ":@"O",
                            @"PH":@"AS",
                            @"FI":@"E",
                            @"FR":@"E",
                            @"GA":@"AF",
                            @"GM":@"AF",
                            @"GE":@"E",
                            @"GH":@"AF",
                            @"GI":@"E",
                            @"GD":@"S",
                            @"GL":@"N",
                            @"GP":@"S",
                            @"GF":@"S",
                            @"GU":@"AF",
                            @"GT":@"S",
                            @"GG":@"E",
                            @"GN":@"AF",
                            @"GW":@"AF",
                            @"GQ":@"AF",
                            @"GY":@"S",
                            @"HT":@"S",
                            @"HN":@"S",
                            @"HU":@"E",
                            @"IE":@"AS",
                            @"BV":@"ANT",
                            @"CX":@"O",
                            @"HM":@"ANT",
                            @"AF":@"O",
                            @"IM":@"E",
                            @"RE":@"AF",
                            @"KY":@"S",
                            @"CC":@"O",
                            @"CK":@"O",
                            @"FO":@"E",
                            @"GS":@"ANT",
                            @"FK":@"S",
                            @"MP":@"O",
                            @"MH":@"O",
                            @"UM":@"O",
                            @"PN":@"S",
                            @"SB":@"O",
                            @"TC":@"S",
                            @"VG":@"S",
                            @"VI":@"S",
                            @"ID":@"AS",
                            @"IR":@"AS",
                            @"IQ":@"AS",
                            @"IE":@"E",
                            @"IS":@"E",
                            @"IL":@"AS",
                            @"IT":@"E",
                            @"IN":@"AS",
                            @"JM":@"S",
                            @"JP":@"AS",
                            @"JE":@"E",
                            @"JO":@"AS",
                            @"KZ":@"AS",
                            @"KE":@"AF",
                            @"KG":@"AS",
                            @"KI":@"O",
                            @"KW":@"AS",
                            @"LA":@"AS",
                            @"LV":@"E",
                            @"LR":@"AF",
                            @"LI":@"E",
                            @"LT":@"E",
                            @"LB":@"AS",
                            @"LY":@"AF",
                            @"LU":@"E",
                            @"MK":@"E",
                            @"MG":@"AF",
                            @"MW":@"AF",
                            @"MV":@"AS",
                            @"ML":@"AF",
                            @"MT":@"E",
                            @"MA":@"AF",
                            @"MQ":@"S",
                            @"MU":@"AF",
                            @"MR":@"AF",
                            @"YT":@"AF",
                            @"MX":@"N",
                            @"FM":@"O",
                            @"MZ":@"AF",
                            @"MD":@"E",
                            @"MN":@"AS",
                            @"ME":@"E",
                            @"MS":@"S",
                            @"MC":@"E",
                            @"MM":@"AS",
                            @"NA":@"AF",
                            @"NR":@"O",
                            @"NP":@"AS",
                            @"NI":@"S",
                            @"NG":@"AF",
                            @"NU":@"O",
                            @"NE":@"AF",
                            @"NO":@"E",
                            @"NC":@"O",
                            @"NZ":@"O",
                            @"OM":@"AS",
                            @"NL":@"E",
                            @"PK":@"AS",
                            @"PW":@"O",
                            @"PS":@"AS",
                            @"PA":@"S",
                            @"PG":@"O",
                            @"PY":@"S",
                            @"PE":@"S",
                            @"PF":@"O",
                            @"PL":@"E",
                            @"PT":@"E",
                            @"PR":@"S",
                            @"QA":@"AS",
                            @"HK":@"AS",
                            @"MO":@"AS",
                            @"GB":@"E",
                            @"CF":@"E",
                            @"DO":@"S",
                            @"CZ":@"E",
                            @"ZA":@"AF",
                            @"RO":@"E",
                            @"RU":@"E",
                            @"RW":@"AF",
                            @"UM":@"S",
                            @"KN":@"S",
                            @"SH":@"AF",
                            @"LC":@"S",
                            @"MF":@"S",
                            @"VC":@"S",
                            @"PM":@"N",
                            @"WS":@"O",
                            @"AS":@"O",
                            @"SM":@"E",
                            @"EH":@"AF",
                            @"ST":@"AF",
                            @"SN":@"AF",
                            @"SC":@"AF",
                            @"RS":@"E",
                            @"SL":@"AF",
                            @"SG":@"AS",
                            @"SR":@"S",
                            @"SJ":@"E",
                            @"SZ":@"AF",
                            @"TJ":@"AS",
                            @"TH":@"AS",
                            @"TW":@"AS",
                            @"TZ":@"AF",
                            @"IO":@"O",
                            @"TF":@"O",
                            @"TL":@"AS",
                            @"TG":@"AF",
                            @"TK":@"O",
                            @"TO":@"O",
                            @"TT":@"S",
                            @"TN":@"AF",
                            @"TM":@"AS",
                            @"TR":@"AS",
                            @"TV":@"O",
                            @"TD":@"AF",
                            @"UA":@"E",
                            @"UG":@"AF",
                            @"AE":@"AS",
                            @"UY":@"S",
                            @"UZ":@"AS",
                            @"VZ":@"O",
                            @"VA":@"E",
                            @"VE":@"S",
                            @"VN":@"AS",
                            @"WF":@"O",
                            @"CL":@"S",
                            @"CN":@"AS",
                            @"CY":@"E",
                            @"ZM":@"AF",
                            @"ZW":@"AF"};
```